# How can I notify about an error when requesting/downloading data from the Kotlin server?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Good day!
I'm new to programming and in the process of developing an application, I encountered this problem:
There is an application written in Kotlin that makes a request to the server using the Retrofit2 library.
I need to implement a notification to the user when the connection is lost, the server fails, etc.
Notification tied just to check the Internet connection does not roll.
What I've already tried:

- I tried to catch and handle exceptions for the Call method via try/cath, but nothing comes out. if I understand correctly, this is due to the fact that the Retrofit2 library itself correctly handles exceptions related to connection loss, server failure, etc.
- another option was to logically track whether the correct data came from the server or not, and then notify the user based on this. I tried to catch on to the presence of data in CurrentDataWeather, but also so far without success.
- there was also an option to use response.isSuccessful to check the correctness of the received data, but even without an Internet connection, isSuccessful returns true.

Please help me with advice. Where to dig?
Thank you very much!